# Angular Web App Unable to Access User Facing Camera on iOS Mobile Devices

Tags: ios, angular, ipad, web-applications

I have the following Angular code from a web-app which is running on an iPad. In essence, all I am doing is starting up a camera & scanning a qr code. However, across all browsers the environment camera is the one being used and is pointing away rom the user. I need to be using the user facing camera.

The implementation below contains a hacky way in which I tried to flip the camera to the front facing one, since setting the default video: { facingMode: 'user' } did not work.

Thoughts?

----HTML FILE----

```
<video #videoElement autoplay></video>
```

----TS FILE ----

```
activateCamera(): void {

this.isCameraActivated = true;

WebcamUtil.getAvailableVideoInputs()

.then((mediaDevices: MediaDeviceInfo[]) => {

const videoConstraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {

video: { facingMode: 'environment' } // Use the rear camera initially

};

const switchCamera = (): void => {

if (typeof videoConstraints.video === 'object' && videoConstraints.video.facingMode === 'environment') {

videoConstraints.video.facingMode = 'user'; // Switch to front camera

} else {

videoConstraints.video = { facingMode: 'environment' }; // Switch back to rear camera

}

// Re-initialize the camera stream with the updated video constraints

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(videoConstraints)

.then((stream: MediaStream) => {

const videoElement = this.videoElement.nativeElement;

if (videoElement) {

videoElement.srcObject = stream;

videoElement.play();

//log devices after permissions are granted

mediaDevices.filter(d => console.log('device: ',d.label));

// Start scanning for QR code

this.qrCodeScannerService.startScanning(videoElement, (qrCode: string) => {

console.log('QR code scanned:', qrCode);

this.validateQRCode(qrCode);

});

}

})

.catch((error: any) => {

console.error('Error accessing media devices or camera:', error);

});

};

switchCamera(); // Call the function to initially start with the rear camera

})

.catch((error: any) => {

console.error('Error accessing media devices or camera:', error);

});

}
```

Setting the facing mode to video: { facingMode: 'user' } by default, flipping the default camera which starts to user. Tried across Safari, Chrome, Edge, Brave browsers. All these browsers fire up the environments cam and not the user facing camera on iOS mobile devices.

Comment: Why would I scan a QR code from the front facing camera?  I can't center the camera if I can't see the screen to scan it?  Seems to me rear facing would be what you want anyway, so the user can "see" the QR code they are scanning in the viewfinder?